# PostgreSQL: Query DB for rows containing integer[] > or < than specified value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table which stores historical temperatures for the past 5 days stored in an integer[] column based on city. The question is: How can I query for entries which have a value great than or less than a specified value? Here's an example table:

```
+=========+==================+
| city    | temps            |
+=========+==================+
| Seattle | {65,72,63,56,72} |
+---------+------------------+
| Miami   | {83,75,69,72,79} |
+---------+------------------+
```

Let's say I want to query for cities which have experienced a temp higher than 80. In this example only Miami has experienced temps higher than 80, so only that row should be returned. I've tried a few queries with no success, looked into intarray, but that doesn't seem to solve my problem either. Thanks much!

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: Nice question. Sample data, expected results, Pg version, clear description. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an alternative to a_horse_with_no_name's solution, the simplest option is to use `<` and [the `any` row-or-array comparision](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html) with the array:

```
SELECT city FROM cities WHERE 80 < any (temps);
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/81c7f).

It is not necessary to unnest the array, as `any` and `all` work on arrays as well as on rowsets.

Unlike using the array operators, this operation does not benefit from and can not use an index (b-tree or GIN) on `temps`, so a normalized design that splits `temps` into a separate table with foreign-key reference to `cities` may actually be faster if you have lots of cities and/or lots of samples.

Earlier I suggested that you may want to [use a `GIN` array index and the array operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4059785/398670), but I was mistaken. These do not support the desired operation; I made an error in my testing that made them appear to.

For frequent updates I'd normalize it into another table and btree-index that table. If there's only a small amount of data I wouldn't bother with indexes and I'd just use `< any (temps)`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your table is named `readings`:

Find cities where at least one temperature is bigger than 80:

```
select *
from readings r
where exists (select 1 
              from unnest(r.temps) i
              where i > 80)
```

Find cities where *all* temperatures are bigger than 68:

```
select *
from readings r
where 68 < all (select i
                from unnest(r.temps) i)
```

Comment: this absolutely solves my problem. do you predict much of a performance penalty by the use of unnest?

Comment: @JoshuaBurns: no, I wouldn't expect that as the number of readings per city seems to be quite small. I would worry if they get more. In that case you might want to consider a more normalized design.

Comment: You don't need to `unnest` the arrays, you can use them directly in `any` and `all`. See added answer.

Comment: @CraigRinger: ah. Thanks. I wasn't aware of that (you live and learn ;) )

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I only picked it up from another SO answer recently, along with the awesome `LIKE ANY` trick.